# Save or update operation of entity that contains date field with hibernate subtracts one day

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I have a simple CRUD application. I use Hibernate as ORM framework  and MySQL as db. I have encountered problem saving or updating one of my entity to db. This problem relates to subtracting the entered date on the form by one day. So date field of entity is incorrect in db.
Code snippet below:

#### db.properties

```
#
# JDBC connection properties
#
jdbc.driver=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hb_restaurants?useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&serverTimezone=UTC
jdbc.user=root
jdbc.password=root

#
# Connection pool properties
#
connection.pool.initialPoolSize=5
connection.pool.minPoolSize=5
connection.pool.maxPoolSize=20
connection.pool.maxIdleTime=30000

#
# Hibernate properties
#
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
hibernate.show_sql=true
hibernate.packagesToScan=ru.icoltd.rvs.entity
```

#### Entity class

```
  @Entity
    @Table(name = "menus")
    public class Menu {
    
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column(name = "id")
        private Integer id;
    
        @NotNull
        @Column(name = "name")
        private String name;
    
        @Column(name = "date")
        private LocalDate date;
    
        @ManyToOne(cascade = {
                CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE,
                CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH})
        @JoinColumn(name = "restaurant_id")
        private Restaurant restaurant;
    
        @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "menu", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        @Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
        private List<Dish> dishes;
    
        @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "menu", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        @Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
        private List<Vote> votes;

        // getters and setters
```

#### Table

```
CREATE TABLE `menus`
(
    `id`            int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name`          varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
    `restaurant_id` int(11)     DEFAULT NULL,
    `date`          date    DEFAULT NULL,
    KEY `fk_restaurant_idx` (`restaurant_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `fk_restaurant_id` FOREIGN KEY (`restaurant_id`) REFERENCES `restaurants` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

#### Dao class

```
@Repository
@Slf4j
public class MenuDAOImpl implements MenuDAO {

    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Autowired
    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    @Override
    public void saveMenu(Menu menu) {
        Session currentSession = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        currentSession.saveOrUpdate(menu);
    }
```

I can create a brand new menu or update data of existing menu on the form. After that I submit form, my controller method is called and performs save or update operation.
*In `MenuDaoImpl` class menu object is passed  with correct value of field `date`.* (example I entered value 21.07.2019).
But after performing operation `saveOrUpdate()` entry is saved in db with value 20.07.2019. Adding 1 day every time is not a solution for me.
How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a problem with timezones.
Try to specify the timezone with hibernate-utils (https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-date-time)

```
session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().withOptions()
  .jdbcTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"))
  .openSession();
```

or use a zoned date object like ZonedDateTime.

Comment: I've tried to specify timezone option for session, but it didn't help. I'll try to use ZonedDateTime as type of date.